# Sqoop import null values from mysql doesn't replace Null

Tags: mysql, null, hive, sqoop

In mysql there is a table with some columns have null values. I want to sqoop import the table to hive. When I do sqoop import I am getting all null values in the columns that have null in the mysql table.

I am doing the following

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:xxxxxx --username xxxx --password xxxx \
--query "select * from  hive_db.xxxx where \$CONDITIONS" --null-string '' \
--null-non-string '' -m 1 --hive-import --hive-database hivedatabase \
--hive-table table --as-parquetfile --create-hive-table --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/hivedatabase.db/table
```

But I am still getting the hive columns as Null intsead of empty

Why is this happening? How do I get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is used when you import data as textfile to specify null values.

a workaround could be change the null values in your query. depending on your databse engine, it could be something like this (sql server sintax)

--query "select isnull(columnA,''), isnull(columnB,''), etc from yourTable where $conditions"

Comment: so can't we use it with parquet

Comment: yes, a workaround(more painfull) is transform the null values in your query

Comment: please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355455/sqoop-import-newly-added-column-to-mysql-table-to-existing-hive-table

Answer (score -1):

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:xxxxxx --username xxxx --password xxxx \
--query "select * from  hive_db.xxxx where \$CONDITIONS" --null-string " " \
--null-non-string " " -m 1 --hive-import --hive-database hivedatabase \
--hive-table table --as-parquetfile --create-hive-table --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/hivedatabase.db/table
```